# Apache 2 server has 5 sec delay

Tags: php, curl, apache2

I have a problem, that I can not solve. Some of the communication (~10-20%) between the frontend and the backend server has stuck. Can anyone give me an advice?

### Frontend PHP  --------- curl --------> Backend PHP

- The frontend sends the request and it is arriving immediately to the Apache
- In the backend log there is a 5 sec delay for the start of the operation
- The backend log says that the operation was fast

### Example:

- frontend curl log:

  ```
  16:30:00.00 - Runtime: 5.2454
  ```
- backend apache access log:

  ```
  16:30:00.01 - /backend/....
  ```
- backend log:

  ```
  16:30:05.01 - Runtime: 0.2254
  ```

### The way that I am logging:

- Frontend log:

  ```
  <?php
  ....
  startTime
  send curl request to Backend IP
  write to the log: currentTime, currentTime-startTime
  ...
  ?>
  ```
- Backend log:

  ```
  <?php
  startTime
  PHP/MySQL/Redis/etc
  write to the log: currentTime, currentTime-startTime
  ?>
  ```

## Server

- Debian 6.0.3
- Apache/2.2.16
- PHP 5.3.3
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49
- Redis server 2.4.2

Comment: you're doing a curl request to your own server? That's HIGHLY inefficient.

Comment: they are two different servers, the communication is under a Redis based cache. It is quite quick

Comment: Then check stuff like firewalls, reverse DNS lookups, apache doing 'whois' lookups, etc.. if the actual code is fast, then it's something outside of php doing this.

Comment: I have tried all of these and I am using IP :(

Comment: it can even be mysql doing it. e.g. if your mysql login account is `foo@example.com`, mysql has do a reverse dns lookup on the IP you're connecting from to see if it IS example.com.

Comment: login account is via localhost, and localhost is in the hosts file (Or maybe I have misunderstood your comment) and those PHPs can do this delay which are not using mysql

Comment: Can you try to locate the culprit by testing a) a static page, b) a minimal php page, c) a minimal php page that connects to mysql, ... ?